# In hive, how to query a table with group by only a substring of the column?

Tags: regex, hive

For example, if there's a sample table "sample_hive_tables" with the column "path". If there're total 3 records with the path as

```
"abc&page_id=defghi&other_parameters"
"abc&page_id=defghi"
"abc&page_id=efghi"
"abc"
```

The query should tell us records with page_id "defghi" appears twice and records with page_id  "efghi" appears once. Value of page_id will start with "&page_id=" and end with nothing or "&". The page_id may not exist for some records in the table. How to write a query to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new column with the values between `page_id=` and `(&,")` and use that to group by and count.

```
select val,count(val) from
(
    select regexp_extract(path,(?<=page_id=).*?(?=\"|&)) as val 
    from sample_hive_tables
) a
group by val;
```

Note: I am assuming there is a " at the end of each string, if not use the following regex `(?<=page_id=)(.*?)(?=\b|&)`